# MySQL (Xampp) will not start on Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been using Xampp for a few weeks and so far I had no problem in launching MySQL. This time, when I ran Xampp as administrator (as usual), I got this error:

> Problem detected!
>   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57"!

I changed the port from 3306 to 3307 in C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini and restarted my computer, and now I get this error:

> "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly..."

I found no working solution online, and I would appreciate it if you could help me with this.

This is what I see in the control panel:
[mysql (xampp) problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFPoa.png)

This is mysql_error.log:[mysql_error.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLIsL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this quick fix:

1. Close and exit Xampp server / control panel
2. Go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data\ dir (or where your xampp resides)
3. Delete **ibdata1** file
4. Restart xampp

Let me know the result.

Comment: So, earlier today I removed ibdata from C:\xampp\mysql\data. The error was still there, so I followed a suggestion to uninstall the MySQL Server 5.7 because it collides with the Xampp MySQL Server. But still it was unresolved. Finally, I removed ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 from C:\xampp\mysql\data and now MySQL in Xampp is running, but I have an other issue: Whenever I login to phpmyadmin, I can view the DB that I had created, but not the tables that they consist. Also, I can't even create a new database now. Every time I try, phpmyadmin just freezes. Do you know why?

Comment: Should I remove and reinstall Xampp? Or maybe try to install both Xampp and MySQL Workbench in Ubuntu? I'm not sure if this is a Windows problem though. I'm new to this and would like some advice :)

Comment: Try to remove and reinstall Xampp, make sure to delete unnecessary files after uninstall. Restart your PC then reinstall Xampp following the instruction from the site. I am running Windows 8.1 and I have no problem using Xampp.

Comment: I did that and now I see the same error again : "Problem detected! Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57"!"

Answer (score 1):

hello i have low ranking that's why i help out through answer

this issue is related to your port configuration because sometime port is allocate by the other application in windwow
keep in mind firstly your skype is in logout mode or check their port configuration or 
2nd step 
You can change the port number to 3308 from 3306 in \xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini file.
3rd step : restart your xammp and check and otherwise uninstall 
and download wamp

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can helps cause I'm using Wamp (not Xampp), but I must disable Skype before it xan works,

Regards,

Charles

Comment: but skype troubles apache not mysql :P

Comment: Yes, I did that already. Skype uses port 80, so I switched xampp to use port 81. But the problem is with port 3306, so I don't think Skype is the reason..

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution after all, without having to edit any my.ini files or installing and uninstalling stuff. Just in case someone else faces with this problem, I just used two commands in cmd:

```
netstat -a -t -n -o|grep 3306
```

Which tells which program uses port 3306. We just want the PID of the program - say it's 2588 - and then type:

```
taskkill /pid 2588 /f
```

I restarted Xampp and it worked.